# visual studio adds a lot of break points when executing code

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

For some unknown reason, my visual studio adds many break marks in my code.
Some where I believe i had some in the past and some in utterly nonsense positions.
I have found nothing in the web. Dont know if thats a bug or if I am using it incorrectly.

Anyone had that before or knows how to resolve this?
I can remove them point by point until my app runs through but as soon as I start debugging, they are beeing readded. When I stop debugging, they are gone again. I was even able to capture one sample beeing added:
[image]

It litterally makes debugging impossible. I cant remove 50 break points whenever I want to debug...

Workaround #1
I have found kind of a workaround by going over Debug -> delete all Break points.

Be aware, this will delete your wanted breakpoints as well.

Comment: Breakpoints are preserved in the *hidden* .vs subdirectory of the project.  If this directory or its files are readonly for some reason (like a source control accident) then you'll always get old breakpoints back.  Closing the solution and deleting the directory ought to provide relief.